# prename удалить n символов до точки

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Привет! 
как используя prename удалить n симвлов в названии, после которых стоит точка и еще неопределенное количество символов?
Пример:

```
Some file. - pattern 2 - some text-4353fuhfi45.1234
```

так вот в данном случе нужно удалить -4353fuhfi45

p.s. самое главное наверное для понимания забыл, должно быть так:

```
Some file. - pattern 2 - some text.1234
```

Comment: Что такое `n` в условии?

Comment: ну цифра. допустим там 16 ненужных мне букво-цифр. вот. их надо убрать

Comment: Тогда см. мой ответ, вроде так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если правильно понял условие:

```
#!/bin/sh

N=12
FN="Some file. - pattern 2 - some text-4353fuhfi45.1234"

touch "$FN"
echo "Before:"
find -name "*.1234"

rename "s/.{$N}([.][^.]+)$/\$1/" "$FN"

echo "After:"
find -name "*.1234"
```

Comment: @beliy да, оба варианта работают, вроде то что нужно! Спасибо всем:) p.s. а не подкините ссылку, где почитать можно про функционал этих скобок в sed? круглые вроде как создают группу, к которой потом можно обращаться, но хотелось бы наверняка. пытаюсь что-то нагуглить, пока не очень

Comment: @jinxted, у меня нет `sed`, решение занимает ровно одну строчку без излишеств и привлечения лишних сущностей в виде `sed` и `awk`. Используется ровно то, что сказано в `man prename` - Perl regular expressions.  Вот и гуглить по ним, это база для любых других языков и областей применения. Например: [тык](http://citforum.ru/internet/perl/regexp/), [тык](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/pcre_perl_intro.txt.html).

Comment: пардон, почему-то в голову этот сед засел, regexp конечно же. то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: `rename` тут лишний, исходя из условия всё можно сделать встроенными средствами так же в одну строку (`${VAR%/%%PATTERN}`, `${VAR#/##PATTERN}`).

Comment: @0andriy, если не требуется переименовывать файл - да, так короче.

Comment: Речь не в короче, а в быстрее. `mv` + shell переименует быстрее кмк, чем `rename` в данном случае.

Comment: @0andriy, а не пофиг? По мне так краткость и простота изложения в шелл-скриптах важней, а скорость в них дело тыщнадцатое. Как оно поможет, если сам скрипт - дамп терабайтной базы? Но это уж дело вкуса :)

Answer (score 1):

Это не prename, но возможно поможет вариант удаление лишнего куска на чистом баше

```
fileName='text-4353fuhfi45.1234'
extFile=$( echo $fileName | awk -F . '{print $NF}' )
endFileName=$( echo  $fileName |  sed "s/\(.*\)\(-.*\)/\"\1.$extFile\"/" )

echo $endFileName
```